# how to make gui elements like a button on every device look like the native gui in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

hi i have a question about the gui of a android application.

when i start a project and select 2.3.3 as my api version. i add some gui stuff like a button and then run the code on a 4.0.3 device.

the problem is now: the button looks like a 2.3.3 button and not like the 4.0.3 version.

is there any way to change this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use one of the `Holo` themes for API Level 11+:

1. Create `res/values` folder
2. Define your application theme like this:

   ```
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme" />
   ```
3. Create `res/values-v11` folder
4. Define your application theme like this:

   ```
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" />
   ```
5. Use `AppTheme` in `AndroidManifest.xml`

For further reading, see section *Using Holo while supporting Android 2.x* in [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/holo-everywhere.html) article.

Answer (score 1):

And if you want Holo for 2.3.3 applications I can recommend [this](https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere) project. Just follow the instructions on the site on how to use it.